# Scrapy callback asynchronous

Tags: python, scrapy

```
    def parse(self, response):
        category_names = []
        category_urls = []

        for item in response.css("#zg_browseRoot ul li"):
            category_url = item.css("a").css(self.CSS_URL).extract()
            category_name = item.css("a").css(self.CSS_TEXT).extract()
            category_url = [
                self.parse_url(category_url, 4) for category_url in category_url
            ]
            (category_url,) = category_url
            (category_name,) = category_name
            category_names.append(category_name)
            category_urls.append(category_url)
        for c_name, url in zip(category_names, category_urls):
            self.c_name = [c_name]
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_categories)

    def parse_url(self, url, number):
        parse = urlparse(url)
        split = parse.path.split("/")[:number]
        return f'{self.BASE_URL}{"/".join(split)}'

    def parse_categories(self, response):
        sub_names = []
        sub_urls = []

        for item in response.css("#zg_browseRoot ul ul li"):
            sub_name = item.css("a").css(self.CSS_TEXT).extract()
            sub_url = item.css("a").css(self.CSS_URL).extract()
            sub_url = [self.parse_url(sub_url, 5) for sub_url in sub_url]
            (sub_url,) = sub_url
            (sub_name,) = sub_name

            sub_names.append(sub_name)
            sub_urls.append(sub_url)

        for sub_name, url in zip(sub_names, sub_urls):
            self.sub_name = [sub_name]
            # print("{}: {}, {}".format(url, self.sub_name, self.c_name))
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_subcategories)

    def parse_subcategories(self, response):
        url = self.parse_url(response.request.url, 5)
        print(f"{self.c_name}, {self.sub_name}, {url}")
```

Hello everyone,
I'm having an issue with my Scrapy approach. I'm trying to scrape page which has categories and subcategories in which are items. I want to include category and subcategory with each item scraped.
The problem is that the Scrapys callback function is asynchronous and zipping the URLs with names doesn't seem to work, because the for loop is processed first, URLs are stored in a generator and names are staying behind. Can anyone help me to work around this?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm not sure I understand the problem you are facing. Am I right to assume that all you want to do is to **`yield` new requests and send arbitrary data along with the request for the callback function to access**? (Like send `category_names` with the request so `parse_categories` method can access) Or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining enough. But yes, that's exactly what I want to do. @renatodvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary data along with the requests by using th `cb_kwargs` parameter. You can read about the details [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs).

Here is a simplified example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="some-element"]')
    for row in rows:
        request_url = row.xpath('a/@href').get()
        category = row.xpath('a/text()').get()
        yield Request(
            url=request_url,
            callback=self.parse_category,
            cb_kwargs={'category': category}
        )

def parse_category(self, response, category): # Notice category arg in the func
    # Process here
    yield item
```

**The data inserted in `cb_kwargs` is passed as a keyword arg into the callback function, so the key in the dict must match the name of the argument in the method definiton.**

*`cb_kwargs` were introduced in Scrapy v1.7, if you are using an older version you should use the `meta` param. You can read about it [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta), notice that the use is slightly different.*